# Array which holds the data of 9000 English Words (Pig Latin Game)

Tags: java

I am working on a mini Project for developing a Pig Latin Game. I have a text file which contains round about 9000 English words. I made a GUI which randomly selects a word from the list and changes it with the some editions and asks the user to guess the words. What should be the best way to store 9000 English words? I don't want to use I/O![image]

Comment: Are you asking which class from the [collection framework](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/collections/overview.html) to use?

Comment: `What should be the best way to hold English words` what do you mean with that? Are you looking for a new way to store them persistently or are you looking for a way to store them during runtime?

Comment: So why don't you just use a simple ArrayList, or HashSet since you don't need ordering?

Comment: @Tom I only need to store them during runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An array of String objects is best. Your are not modifying the size of the structure and you want to quickly access an arbitrary element.

Comment: And what happens if he adds another word to the file? Should he change the code every time he adds a word?

Comment: It's the most efficient way to store the strings. His question is "What should be the best way to store 9000 English words?". 9000.

Comment: Currently 9000. But nevermind, it is up to OP to decided if he want to use an array or not.

Comment: Initially I tested some words with the Array and it just went fine. I wasn't sure about the words greater than couple of thousands.

Comment: Thousands of words are fine for an array. Most english words are about 5 characters. 9000 words will be around 45kb which is not something to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

Do they need to be in any specific order? If not, use an `ArrayList`. Look at this [Java Site](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/collections/overview.html) for others if you don't like that one.